# Windows Phone 8 app crashes when redirecting between pages

Tags: windows-phone-8, crash, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a hybrid app which works fine on android and ios. But in windows, at times application crashes when redirecting between pages. I am getting following error messages in Visual Studio output window.

```
    System.SystemException
    Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
```

It breaks the application at following point in App.xaml.cs.

```
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        }
    }
```

I have no idea which part of code is causing this and I have never seen any such crash before.

Please throw some light on this issue!

Thanking you in anticipation!

Comment: post you code for redirecting to other page that you are using

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx

Comment: @sałe is this issue because of some unhandled exception in javascript?

Comment: @user3917905 Tell me. You stated that you have no idea which part of code is causing the problem so I gave you the option that might help a lot.

Comment: Thank you all. There was an unhandled exception n javascript which caused the application to crash. I have fixed it now. Thank you once again!